# Math logic, converting scale-able numbers to a percent

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, linear-algebra, equation

I'm having some issues figuring out the best way to go about this. I want to display a percent of 0-100. My input(X) is a distance in meters. The closer X is to 0 I want the percent to be closer to 100.

My issue is that the person has to be able to know if they are getting closer to 0. No matter how far the range is. So if they are 10000 meters away and get to 9900 meters I need the percent to increase. But the same if they are 50 meters away and get to 45 meters.

Right now i'm doing

```
100 - ((playerDistance / max) * 100)
```

where max is the maximum value of meters someone can be. which for my situation is around 300,000. This works if they travel far. But once they get within a couple thousand meters it loses all precision since it will be 99% for a long time.

Comment: *"The closer X is to 0 I want the percent to be closer to 100."* `100 - ((500/500) * 100)` is `0` not `100%`.

Comment: You could approach your problem by drawing (by hand) what would look like your function, then do a (little) math for a regression (be it with a sigmoid or a polynomial one or whatever kind of function which can look alike). You should note that depending on your choice, people at the very end (or the very start, or the very middle) may feel like an infinite road seeing no progress or such, but those "spec" are up to you

Answer (score 1):

You can apply any function that has value 1 (100%) for argument 0 and smoothly decreases.

A pair of examples (Python syntax)

```
100.0 * math.exp( - dist / 1000.0)
100.0 * math.pow(1 + dist, -0.3)
```

Note that you cannot provide integer percent values covering all needed range, so you  have to show at least three decimal digits after point (like 54.321).

Aslo note that exponent approach provides equal percent increments for equal `distance1/distance2` ratios

Comment: I don't quite understand. What is the 1000 and -0.3 numbers you have?

Comment: Scale values to provide reliable results in wide distance range (you can change them to better results). Without 1000 divider exponent decreases too fast and give too small values for dist =100 etc. The same for hyperbola in the second example - `1/(1+dist)` gives 10% for dist =9